# API with paginated data, seeking advice

Tags: javascript, axios

So i'm seeking for a couple of questions to be answered. I am using a api which returns a list of products (15000+) how ever they use pagination so it only returns 20 per page.

I would like to be able to show all of this data on my shop so users can search through it etc... however, issue... it takes A LONG time to loop through it etc etc.

Is there a good method to do this? Shall I just loop through all the data and allow it to be added into an array once loaded? Is there something "special" we can do with the pagination?

I am new to this, and just seeking advice on the above.

Kind Regards,
Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few thoughts that strike me straight away so let's cover those first:
From a pure UX perspective, it's very VERY unlikely that any user will ever need or click through 15k+ rows of whatever. So loading them all doesn't serve your user even if you could figure out how to do this in a efficient way.

Instead, look at what serves your users which likely in this case is some sort of filtering or search options. I would look into if your API has any support for things like categories (that should be a set smaller than 1 request maybe) which is much easier to display to get the user to cut down a lot of the data set. Then also look into if they offer some sort of query or search filter, maybe the names of whatever is being displayed. This further lets your users zoom down to a dataset that is manageable (roughly 100 items max). From there, 20 items per page is just 5 pages. Still though, you should only really load 1 page at a time and focus on better ways to offer SORTING, if you can find what the user needs on the first page, you don't need to load those 4 other pages. Hope that gives you some ideas of what to look for inside your API, or what to add if you can add it yourself.

If not, perhaps it would be worth considering loading the data into your own database and set up some background/nightly task that fetches any updates from the API and stores them. Then you build your own API around your own database that has functionality for filtering/searching.

A final option is indeed to simply ask for the first page, and then display that while you wait for the 2nd page to load. But this risks making an awful amount of wasted requests which wastes not only your users bandwidth but also puts pressure on the API for what is likely going to be wasted work. So there are a few other UX ideas around this as well, like infinite scrolling. Load the first 1 or 2 pages then stop, until the users scrolls past the first page and a half, then request page 3 etc. This way you only load pages as the user scrolls but it's a bit more fluid than pagination with numbering. Still, you'd likely want to offer some way to sort this set so that it becomes more likely that they'll find what they need in the first few "pages".

Comment: Thank you for this reply! Its nice to get some indepth reply... The API in question is here: https://www.g2a.com/integration-api/documentation/export/ and as you can see - the get products is not the most useful so i guess adding search params will not be the best approach - so would you suggest the database aproach instead?

Comment: I would only do that (and the infinite scroll option) if I had no other choice. Maintaining a copy of their database isn't going to be easy and the UX of the infinite scroll still won't be great. But it is a bit odd that they don't seem to offer any way to filter based on game title. As a first step, I would reach out to their support (if they have one) and ask about that to be sure, or request if they can add it even. If not, I would still try to instead find "good enough" UX while only showing a few pages at a time. They do offer a few filter options, maybe you could make good use of those?

Comment: Thank you for your advice :-) I shall look into it! :-)

Comment: Perhaps things like "From last week" by using the updatedAtFrom/updatedAtTo, or things like price ranges "Cheap, Affordable, Expensive" and precoding those by using minPriceFrom/minPriceTo?

Comment: Yeah thats not a bad idea ... the items come back with catagories, its a shame we cant do things like "catagory=steam" or what ever.

Comment: From a quick read in their FAQ https://supporthub.g2a.com/marketplace/en/G2A-Services/export-api-integration-qa it seems they do "hint" at using the Export API to bring products into your own database (since they don't export things like descriptions etc.) but I don't fully understand the setup of their API, perhaps their business/tech support can offer more ideas on what a common setup looks like

Comment: I have sent them an email to offer some advice :-) Thank you so much for your help!